# convert tiff to PDF using PDFClown

Tags: pdf, pdf-conversion

Is it possible to convert tiff file into a PDF file, using pdfclown?

I've started a project using PDFClown, and I'm afarid I got stuck (maybe I'll have to switch to IText now...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. PDFClown supports only JPEG images, as stated on their [Features](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/features.html) page.

Comment: Maybe he can use Image IO to convert the TIFF to JPEG.